# Drop tables without rows in tsql

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I wrote this code:

```
SELECT o.name FROM sysobjects o,sysindexes i WHERE ( o.type = 'U'
      and o.id = i.id
      and i.indid in (0,1)
      and i.rows = 0 )
      order by o.name
GO
```

Whould you please help me to drop those empty tables?

Comment: Where is the problem? Which part of dropping these tables is hard to you? What code did you try so far?

Comment: Thanks SubqueryCrunch! I just don't know how to iterate dropping in a stored procedure.

Comment: A simple, easy and inefficient way to do that is using a cursor. Another option would be generating the drop code with dynamic sql.

Comment: A warning to anyone considering using the above query - it can include a system table called dtproperties which holds diagrams and is not excluded by the query.  You can exclude it by including t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' in the where clause, as long as you don't have any of your own tables that start with DT!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use with caution!

This will generate you a drop script for all the tables in your query.When you print the variable `@sql` you will see only the first 4000 characters of its original code due to limitations in the `PRINT` statement. But when you use `EXEC(@sql)` the whole code will be executed.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql  = ''
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'IF OBJECT_ID(''' + o.name + ''') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ' + o.name + CHAR(10)
FROM sysobjects o,sysindexes i 
WHERE 
(
    o.type = 'U'
    and o.id = i.id
    and i.indid in (0,1)
    and i.rows = 0
)order by o.name
PRINT @sql
```

Comment: You need [ ] round the o.name if your table names have special characters in it like hyphens. -  DROP TABLE [' + t.name + ']' + CHAR(10)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query too:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'IF OBJECT_ID('''+ t.name + ''') > 0 DROP TABLE ' + t.name + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions p
        ON t.object_id = p.object_id
WHERE t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%'
      AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
      AND p.rows = 0
GROUP BY t.name,
         p.rows
ORDER BY t.name;
IF @SQL <> ''
  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

This will generate script for all the tables that have no records and then execute this script.